# How to insert code before the root div "__next" js

Tags: javascript, next.js

When creating a next JS app you always have a root div just after the body div like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="__next">
```

I am using a Javascript plugin that requires me to insert some code immdiately after the body tag. Like this:

```
<body>
//My code here
<div id="__next">
```

Is it possible to do this? If so How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question is to create a _document.js file. This will over-ride the defult document that is created by next.

Documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do using a prependTo function of JQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('<input type="text">').prependTo('body');

   // in your case it would be
   $('<div id="__next">').prependTo('body');
});
```